# @postconstruct giving error in spring

Tags: spring

```
@Service
public class SystemPropertiesServiceImpl implements SystemPropertiesService 
{
  @Autowired
  private SystemPropertiesDao systemPropertiesDao;     

  private static final Properties systemProperties = new Properties();

  @PostConstruct
  public void loadSystemProperties(){
      List<SystemProperties> allProperties = systemPropertiesDao.retrieveAll();
      for ( SystemProperties propertie : allProperties)
      {
         systemProperties.put( propertie.getKey() , propertie.getValue()) ;
      }
      String flag = systemProperties.getProperty( "Flag,null );
  }
}

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EmailService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: jm.gov.agd.common.service.SystemPropertiesService jm.gov.agd.common.service.impl.EmailServiceImpl.systemPropertiesService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemPropertiesServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6 .RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]...
```

I think i had used systemproperties dao method in loadSystemProperties() method which has annotation @postconstruct is creating problem. If I remove @postconstruct then it will compliling properly. Can anyone please tell me solution to this situation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `@PostConstruct` . Please read the exception

Comment: `@Transactional` should be injected in `SystemPropertiesServiceImpl` .Exception saying it could not inject the bean of your service ,

Answer (score 0):

Your DAO needs a transaction.

You can mark it as `@Transactional`. Try to add it to the `loadSystemProperties()` method first. If it does not help add it directly to the DAO class (or implement a transactional service and use the service instead).

Comment: I read many threads and tried keeping transaction in SystemPropertiesServiceImpl class as well as dao class as well as loadSystemProperties() but nothing worked for me. I am having an emailservice class which is having instance of SystemPropertiesServiceImpl class.

Comment: By default, Spring will not aware of the`@PostConstruct` . To enable it, you have to either register `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` or specify the `<context:annotation-config />` in bean configuration file